# How to test the following method inside a component with jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs

This is the method inside the component I am trying to test but I get this error: {TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined}

```
setQuery(newQueryElement) 
    //merge together the current query with the new query element
    var currentQuery = QueryString.parse(this.state.currentProjectQuery);
    Object.assign(currentQuery, newQueryElement);

    //now turn the query into a query string and navigate to it
    var queryString = QueryString.stringify(currentQuery);
    this.props.history.push({
        pathname: this.props.location.pathname,
        search: "?" + queryString
    });
}
```

Comment: can you add the code for your existing test that doesn't work?

Comment: Is this component intended to be used as a route?

Answer (score 0):

You must mock your component with prop `history`:

```
const history = []

const wrapper = shallow(<YourComponent history={history} />
```

Then you can test your `history` object like this:

```
expect(history).toHaveLength(1)
```

Comment: it doesn't work. It says {TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined}. Also I want to test if it is a function or not and the queryString is correctly built

Comment: Can you add your full component and test for better detail?